# Netlogo on Windows - pop-ups in GUI open beyond screen and can't be closed

Tags: popup, netlogo

I was curious if anybody had experienced the same issue: when opening a pop-up in the GUI (e.g., inspect patch, inspect turtle), that pop-up open on the top of the screen in a way that I can't grab the menu bar, this can't close or move it which can be really frustrating at times - see screenshot. The small grey bar on the top-left is an old pop-up that I resized to get it out of the way.

Anyone got an idea how that could be fixed?

I use NetLogo 6.1.1 on an Asus laptop running Windows 10. I tried right-clicking, resizing, etc. but to no avail.

[image: pop-up opens beyond the screen]

Comment: What if you move the main NetLogo window lower on the screen?

Comment: Same thing, unfortunately, pop-up still "attaches" to the top of the screen.

Comment: I see there is now a bug report on this at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/1889